# Timeout while using SCPI commands for Keithley 2230 power supply

Tags: python, instruments, visa

> Blockquote

I'm using a Keithley 2230 triple channel DC power supply for lab automation with [PyVISA](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I want to select the particular channel and set the voltage accordingly. I have attached the program as well as the error.

I have done the following research but I was not successful.

[PyVISA SCPI commands and queries (issue with value update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518230/pyvisa-scpi-commands-and-queries-issue-with-value-update)

[Python SCPI avoiding fixed delays (synchronization issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868412/python-scpi-avoiding-fixed-delays-synchronization-issue)

Program:

```
import visa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
str = 'USB0::0x05E6::0x2230::9102008::INSTR'
inst = rm.open_resource(str)
print inst.query("*IDN?")
######### print the selected channel ##########
print inst.query("INSTrument:SELect?")
######### selected the perticular channel ##########
print inst.query("INSTrument:SELect 2")
```

Commands I got from the official link of keithley DD power supply:

http://assets.tequipment.net/assets/1/26/Documents/Keithley/2220_30_1/2220_30_1_doc_4.pdf

Output Log:

```
Keithley instruments, 2230-30-1, 9102008, 1.15-1.04

CH1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/trails/keithley2230.py", line 9, in <module>
    print inst.query("INSTrument:SELect 2")
  File "C:python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 384, in query
    return self.read()
  File "C:\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 309, in read
    message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
  File "C:\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 283, in read_raw
    chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "C:\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1569, in read
    ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))
  File "C:\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 180, in _return_handler
    raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

Comment: What does `print rm.list_resources()` produce?

Comment: And what happens if you query channel 2 first, and then channel 1?

Comment: print rm.list_resources() produce (u'USB0::0x05E6::0x2230::9102008::INSTR', u'ASRL3::INSTR', u'ASRL10::INSTR')

Comment: what happens if you query channel 2 first, and then channel 1 :  currently I am not able select a particular channel. Output whatever I am getting is the default channel.

Comment: If the default channel responds properly and a timeout only occurs when you try to select a specific channel, maybe you just need a different query string for that? Where did you get the syntax `'INSTrument:SELect 2'`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot to mention, syntax I got from following link:http://assets.tequipment.net/assets/1/26/Documents/Keithley/2220_30_1/2220_30_1_doc_4.pdf

Comment: Looking at the documentation, firstly you should be sending `INSTrument:SELect CH2`, secondly I'm not sure that that command will return a result, so maybe try using `inst.write("INSTrument:SELect 2")` instead of `print inst.read("...")`

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming because of this query:

```
print inst.query("INSTrument:SELect?")
```

Instead I used `print inst.write("INSTrument:SELect?")`.

I am attaching the code snippet for the future users :-)

```
import visa
import pyvisa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print rm.list_resources()
str = 'USB0::0x05E6::0x2230::9102008::INSTR'
inst = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x05E6::0x2230::9102008::INSTR')


print inst.query("*IDN?")

print inst.write("OUTPUT ON")

inst.write("INSTrument:SELect CH1")
print inst.query("INSTrument:SELect?")
print inst.write("OUTPut:ENABle 1")
print inst.write("APPLY CH1,1.11V,1.5A")
```